# How do I prevent my Datepicker from leaving the Dialog and breaking

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a form within a dialog box, but when I use the date picker and attempt to select a date, it disappears and breaks, making the last days of the calendar inaccessible. You can see an example of this behavior in the image linked below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SG3Y.png)

The following code shows the dialog component where I make use of the Datepicker component:

```
<Dialog
  open={open}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
  sx={{}}
>
  <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent>
    <Box
      noValidate
      component="form"
      onSubmit={(evt) => handleSubmit(evt, filterData)}
      sx={{
        display: 'grid',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        m: 'auto',
        width: 'fit-content',
      }}
    >
      <CustomDatePicker
        id="fechaHasta"
        value={fechaHasta}
        startDate={fechaDesde}
        label="END date"
        callback={outputInputChange}
      />
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={() => setOpen(false)} color="primary">
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
          color="primary"
          type="submit"
        >
          Filter
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Box>
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

I have tried several things to solve this problem in my component, including using offset modifiers to change the position, but nothing has worked so far. The following is the code for the Datepicker component:

```
<DatePicker
  id={id}
  name{={id}
  minDate={isEmpty(startDate) ? undefined : startDate}
  maxDate={isEmpty(endDate) ? undefined : endDate}
  label={label}
  variant="inline"
  inputVariant="outlined"
  format="dd/MM/yyyy"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

I would appreciate any information you can offer regarding this issue. It should be noted that this only happens when my modal contains the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a `z-index` to your date picker component. To ensure that it appears above the dialog box, assign a higher value to your z-index property.

Comment: Apparently it does not work since the date selector is still in the same place and does not allow me to access the last days that are hidden no matter how much the z-index value changes